# Eigenvalue of PSD matrices by constrained SDP program

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

Given Lemma 1, I want to prove the following corollary.

**lemma 1 (Rayleigh Quotient)**:
Given matrix $A \succeq 0$,
\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{\min} (A) = \min_{x \in \mathbb R^n}\frac{x^\top A x}{x^\top x}.
\end{equation}

**Corollary**:
Given matrix $A \succeq 0$,
\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{\min}(A) = \underset{U \in \Delta_{n \times n}}{\min} \langle A,U \rangle.
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_{n \times n} \overset{\operatorname{def}}{=} \{M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}~:~M \succeq 0,~\mathrm{Trace}(M) = 1 \}$, and $\langle X, Y\rangle = \mathrm{Trace}(XY)$ denotes the inner product between two symmetric matrices.

I found the following proof in the net, but I cannot totally understand it.

**Proof**:
Let
\begin{equation*}
    U^* = \underset{U \in \Delta_{n \times n}}{\arg\min} \langle A, U\rangle.
\end{equation*}
We take the SVD $A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i u_i^\top$ and $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \dots \leq \lambda_n$. It is clear that $\langle A, U^* \rangle \leq \langle A, u_1 u_1^\top \rangle$ $= \lambda_{\min}(A)$. Next, we need to show $\lambda_{\min}(A) \leq \langle A, U^* \rangle$.

The SVD of $U^* = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i v_i v_i^\top$. If $\lambda_{\min}(A) > \langle A, U^* \rangle$, then $\lambda_{\min}(A) > \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i v_i^\top A v_i$. Since $\sum \sigma_i = 1$, there exists $k$ such that $\lambda_{\min}(A) > v_k^\top A v_k$ which contradicts Lemma 1.

The parts of the proof I do not understand well are:

- Why $\langle A, U^* \rangle \leq \langle A, u_1 u_1^\top \rangle$ is clear?
- Why?

> there exists $k$ such that $\lambda_{\min}(A) > v_k^\top A v_k$ which contradicts Lemma 1

I will be very grateful if you could help me to understand these parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality follows because $u_1 u_1^{\mathsf{T}} \in \Delta_{n \times n}$, and $U^{\ast}$ is the minimizer over that set:

$$
\langle U^{\ast}, A \rangle = \min_{U \in \Delta_{n \times n}} \langle U, A \rangle \leq \langle u_1 u_1^{\mathsf{T}}, A \rangle.
$$

Indeed, you can verify that $u_1 u_1^{\mathsf{T}} \succeq 0$ and its trace is equal to
$$
\mathsf{tr}(u_1 u_1^{\mathsf{T}}) = \mathsf{tr}(u_1^{\mathsf{T}} u_1) = \|u_1\|^2 = 1. 
$$

The second part follows because
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i v_i^{\mathsf{T}} A v_i \geq
\underbrace{\left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i \right)}_{=  1} \cdot \min_{i = 1, \dots, n} \left(
v_i^{\mathsf{T}} A v_i \right).
$$

In particular, the minimum is attained for some index $k$.